# Awaiting Redux Action w/ React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, react-hooks

I'm trying to handle a form submission to show a loading component when the data fetch is occuring. I'd like to display the data when it's been loaded into my `Redux` store.

Right now, I've set up my component to use `React` hooks. While the data loads into my `redux` store successfully, I'm not sure how to "await" the result of the action being completed. Here's a simplified version of what my component looks like:

```
const DataPage = (props) => {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isError, setError] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => { // Reset Filters when dataSource changes...
        setError(false);
        setIsLoading(false);
    }, [dataSource]);

    const handleSubmit = (e, { dataSource }) => {

        e.preventDefault();
        setError(false)
        setIsLoading(true);

         //// IDEALLY THIS IS WHERE THE FIX WOULD GO? TURN THIS INTO ASYNC/AWAIT?
        props.fetchData({ dataSource, token: localStorage.JWT_TOKEN });
    };

    return (    
        <div className="dataPage">
            <form className="dataPage__filters" onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e, { dataSource })}>
                <DataSelector dataSource={dataSource} setDataSource={setDataSource}/>
                <button className="button">
                   Search
                </button>
            </form>
            {isError && <div>Something went wrong...</div>}
            { isLoading ? ( <div>...Loading </div> ) : (
                <div className="dataPage__table">
                    <DataTable /> // This is connected to my redux-store separately through 'connect'
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchData: ({ dataSource, token }) => dispatch(startFetchData({ dataSource, token }))
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(DataPage);
```

The relevant actions (`startFetchData`, and `setData`) are located in another file, and look like this:

```
export const setData = (data) => ({
    type: "SET_DATA",
    data
});

export const startFetchData = ({ dataSource, filter, filterTarget, token }) => {
    return (dispatch) => {

        axios.get(`${'http://localhost:8081'}/api/${dataSource}`, { headers: { authorization: token }})
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch(setData(result));
        });
    }
};
```

I'd like to be able to do this without introducing any new dependencies if possible.

Comment: modifying/updating a state value from a redux dispatch action might be considered an anti-pattern of working react-redux, you should consider moving the `loading` into page's reducer and simply dispatch the action from there, `loading` now will be a prop

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand this comment. Even if I pass the isLoading as a prop to my DataTable, that doesn't solve my problem. I'm still trying wait the fetchData redux action.

Answer (score 2):

**A note for those using TypeScript:** If you want to `await` a promise returned by an action using `useDispatch()` you may see TypeScript complaining about an unnecessary `await`.

In this case make sure to add the correct typing (see [ThunkDispatch](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/d28ab03fd1d2dd1de402928a9589857e97142e09/src/index.d.ts#L20)) to `useDispatch` via generics.

Also with `useEffect()` with [async-await syntax](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9) make sure to wrap your `async` code in another closure because `useEffect()` expects a `void` return value and Typescript otherwise complains about you returning a Promise.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch<ThunkDispatch<any, any, Action>>();

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const myResult = await dispatch(...);
    const anotherResult = await dispatch(...);
    // ...
  })();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware. It's really easy and useful library to able your action to be, instead of objects, functions (including async functions). I'll give you an example:

#### Store.js

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';
import api from './services/api';

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  // With extra argument, in this case, my API):
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(api));
);
```

#### AuthDuck.js

Giving this duck (types, actions and reducers in the same file, see more [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/scaling-your-redux-app-with-ducks-6115955638be))

```js
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
// Types
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
const Types = {
  SIGN_IN_START: 'SIGN_IN_START',
  SIGN_IN_SUCCESS: 'SIGN_IN_SUCCESS',
  SIGN_IN_FAIL: 'SIGN_IN_FAIL'
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
// Actions
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
const signin = function (user) {
  // LOOK HERE!
  // Redux Thunk able you to return a function instead of an object.
  return async function (dispatch, getState, api) {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: Types.SIGN_IN_START });
      const token = await api.access.signin(user);
      dispatch({ type: Types.SIGN_IN_SUCCESS, payload: token });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: Types.SIGN_IN_FAIL, payload: error });
    }
  };
};

export const Actions = { signin };

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
// Reducers
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
export default function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case VeasyCalendarTypes.SIGN_IN_START:
      return { ...state, isLoading: true };
    case VeasyCalendarTypes.SIGN_IN_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, token: action.payload };
    case VeasyCalendarTypes.SIGN_IN_FAIL:
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I hope to helped you, let me know if it worked for your case :)

Best regards